# Angular UI & Bootstrap: Collapse Mobile Navbar on Link Click

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

I have a functioning bootstrap navbar through use of ui.bootstrap of Angular-UI. For the mobile navbar, I want the navbar to collapse when a link is clicked. The toggle button functions as expected, but I can't get the ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" to work on the nav links.

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" ng-controller="NavbarCtrl">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button class="navbar-toggle" type="button" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a href="/" class="navbar-brand">App</a>
   </div>
   <div collapse="isCollapsed" class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="navbar-main">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li ng-repeat="item in menu" ng-class="{active: isActive(item.link)}">
           <a ng-href="{{item.link}}" ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed">{{item.title}}</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

In my controller, the applicable code is:

```
$scope.isCollapsed = true;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue. Not sure if this is the best solution but I just added this in the main controller:

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function(event, toState){
    $scope.navbarCollapse = true;
});
```

It doesn't exactly do what you ask, because it's not triggering the collapse on click event. But it does trigger the collapse on each state change which for this purpose is the same.